# Почему анализ текста с помощью регулярных выражений прерывается в конце строки?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
import re
import urllib.request

def main():
    pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<Block><div id=\"entryContent\">.*)")
    data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/"
                                      "definition/english/hello").read().decode()
        result = pattern.search(data)
        print(result.group("Block"))

    main()
```

Результат:

```
<div id="entryContent"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="entry" sk="hello11" id="hello_1"><ol class="h-g" id="hello_1__1"><div class="top-container"><div class="top-g" id="hello_1__2">
```

По моему пониманию, я должен был получить текст начиная c "<..." до окончания. Специально поставил ".*". Но, почему-то, анализ текста прерывается почти сразу и я получаю только малую часть. Почему там может быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что метасимвол `.` по-умолчанию не совпадает с `\n`.
Используйте регулярное выражение с флагом `DOTALL`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents

---

Для регулярных выражений PCRE этот флаг записывается так:

```
/your_regex/s
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помог совет! Я совсем про это забыл. В моем изначальном шаблоне я использовал "\s", но ошибочка закралась. К сожалению я начал искать её в другом месте. Но с флагом DOTALL намного удобней :)